Problem with integer-valued values in a geofacet grid [R]
I am trying to plot a geographic visualisation using the package geofacet. However when I try to plot the grid I have this error :
>grid_preview(poly_grid)

Error: A custom grid must have positive integer-valued 'col' values

I do not see where the problem is because the col and row variable are rounded and if I use the real geographic coordinates I have no errors (but the spaces between facets is too important to have something visual).
Here is the data :
poly_grid = structure(list(col = c(21, 9, 6, 14, 8, 5, 0, 12, 11, 15, 10, 
9, 13, 5, 3, 1, 9, 12, 5, 23, 14, 9, 8, 17, 23, 13, 25, 17, 18, 
17, 22, 24, 20, 5), row = c(25, 17, 15, 16, 15, 14, 17, 9, 20, 
18, 15, 21, 18, 13, 17, 23, 24, 24, 22, 17, 10, 12, 10, 25, 25, 
22, 20, 15, 0, 3, 21, 15, 5, 8), name = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35"), code = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-34L))

I also join the data with coordinates which normally works (in case it can be useful)
poly_grid_coord = structure(list(col = c(251235, 167749, 146252, 201147, 159088, 
142051, 103061, 188273, 182682, 212837, 176576, 168812, 195580, 
136928, 122634, 109549, 164570, 190556, 136987, 264057, 206556, 
169647, 157707, 221304, 266942, 196649, 281944, 225850, 234266, 
222462, 259135, 274390, 243354, 141764), row = c(154416, 115782, 
108955, 111923, 107289, 101062, 118560, 80090, 133003, 124269, 
107144, 135336, 123579, 97173, 119376, 147282, 150989, 152693, 
143233, 118859, 85151, 95095, 82591, 154720, 156290, 141479, 
132474, 106894, 35815, 52663, 139266, 106543, 58263, 75623), 
    name = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
    "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
    "32", "33", "34", "35"), code = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
    "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
    "17", "18", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
    "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-34L))


0 is not a positive integer. If you change the 0 values in col and row to be positive integers, the code works.

Thank you, that works!
